# for (let key in data) loop 1 or more times with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to loop only one time or I want to loop specified times in for loop.

I have very big JSON and the structure is like this:

```
{
  "-item1" : {
    "added_by" : "admin@gmail.com",
    "id" : "-KlxUo5HGr7sdEsgEea1",
    "name" : "Apivita"
  },
  "-item2" : {
    "added_by" : "admin@gmail.com",
    "id" : "-KlxUq4SgTfefuAB2XH1",
    "name" : "Lierac"
  },
  "-item3" : {
    "added_by" : "admin@gmail.com",
    "id" : "-KlxUs1I3P7z2YDFtQPh",
    "name" : "Bioderma"
  }
}
```

How to loop only one time?

```
// get the object key
for(var key in data) {
  var value = data[key];
}
```

I want only the `item1` object data.
Or the first 5 items
is that easy ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to access only the first item?

Comment: If you want to "loop only once", then you don't want to *loop*.

Comment: Do you want to access only the properties of a specified item (*e.g.* `-item3`)?

Comment: yes only the first item Or i need to specify the first 5 for example

Comment: It's just `var value = data["-item1"]`

Comment: Why is that JSON structure so weird? It looks like it should be an array instead of having keys like `"-item1"`, `"-item2"`, etc.

Comment: this json format is Firebase data structure dont ask me ask google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a counter and exit the loop if the counter has reached its limit:

```js
var counter = 0;
var limit = 3;
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
for (var key in data) {
  var value = data[key];
  console.log('key: ' + key + ' --> value: ' + value);
  if (++counter >= limit) break;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try something below to get a particular value alone.

```
//get item2
var value = data["-item2"]
```

Or if you want to take first 5 values then check below code.

```
// get the object key
var keyVal=1;
for(var key in data) {
  if(keyVal <= 5){
    var value = data[key];        
  }
  keyVal++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help

Comment: This (apparently untested) code does not work: you only increment `keyVal` if it is `>= 5` so you basically never increment it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
var start = 0;
var end = 0;
for(var i = start; i<end; i++){
    var value = data["-item"+i]
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help